# Limit message size in logback

Tags: security, logback

I have a play-application that uses logback. Some of the messages logged by one of the libraries are very large and fills my log with unnecessary statements.

What I want to do is log all messages but limit them on a certain size (e.q. 300 characters). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383867/text-length-limit-in-logback-logging) might help.

Comment: I found that post, but the solution in this example is to use a cxf class and i use the Play Framework. I found this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704470/can-a-logback-message-field-be-truncated-trimmed-to-n-characters
So I will try that as soon as possible to if it is possible to truncate the messages also.

Answer (score 22):

The [format modifiers](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) in the link did the trick. To truncate the message you can do it using `%.-n` where `n` is the maximum length:

```
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %.-512msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
```

This modifier will truncate messages larger than 512 characters and put no padding on the left.